# How can a Qbs build Rule use a product

Tags: qt, build-system, qbs

I want to use Qbs to compile an existing project. This project already contains a code-transformation-tool (my_tool) that is used heavily in this project.

So far I have (simplified):

```
import qbs 1.0

Project {
    Application {
        name: "my_tool"
        files: "my_tool/main.cpp"
        Depends { name: "cpp" }
    }

    Application {
        name: "my_app"
        Group {
            files: 'main.cpp.in'
            fileTags: ['cpp_in']
        }
        Depends { name: "cpp" }

        Rule {
            inputs: ["cpp_in"]
            Artifact {
                fileName: input.baseName
                fileTags: "cpp"
            }
            prepare: {

                var mytool = /* Reference to my_tool */;

                var cmd = new Command(mytool, input.fileName, output.fileName);
                cmd.description = "Generate\t" + input.baseName;
                cmd.highlight = "codegen";
                return cmd;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the reference to my_tool for the command?

Comment: Ther is no tag 'qbs' yet...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is based on an email from Qbs author Joerg Bornemann who allowed me to cite it here.

The property `usings` of Rule allows to add artifacts from products dependencies to the inputs.
In this case we are interested in "application" artifacts.

The list of applications could then be accessed as `input.application`.

```
Application {
    name: "my_app"
    Group {
        files: 'main.cpp.in'
        fileTags: ['cpp_in']
    }
    Depends { name: "cpp" }

    // we need this dependency to make sure that my_tool exists before building my_app
    Depends { name: "my_tool" }

    Rule {
        inputs: ["cpp_in"]
        usings: ["application"] // dependent "application" products appear in inputs
        Artifact {
            fileName: input.completeBaseName
            fileTags: "cpp"
        }
        prepare: {
            // inputs["application"] is a list of "application" products
            var mytool = inputs["application"][0].fileName;
            var cmd = new Command(mytool, [inputs["cpp_in"][0].fileName, output.fileName]);
            cmd.description = "Generate\t" + input.baseName;
            cmd.highlight = "codegen";
            return cmd;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `usings` property in a `Rule` is deprecated since QBS 1.5.0. At the moment I have the same requirement. Using a product artifact in a **non** multiplex `Rule`.

The problem with a multiplex `Rule` is, if a single file in the input set changes, all input artifacts will be re-processed. Which is rather time consuming in my case.